# can not save data to the dynamic DOM when table sorter is used

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

**since this is not a real problem, please ignore this question except you want to solve similar problems with the following code**

I wanted to draw a polygon onto the google map when a dynamic generated table line is clicked. It seems that the data has been successfully saved to that dom, but can simply not be read again outside the $.each() function.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(index) {
        var id = "tableLine_"+index;
        tbody.append(
            '<tr id='+id+' class="tableLine">'+
            '<td>'+ this.status+ '</td>'+
            '<td>'+ this.name+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+ this.city+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+ this.street+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+ this.language+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+ this.distance+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'
        );

        //save data to the specific 'tr'
        $("tr#"+id).data("polygon",this.polygon);

        //this proved that the data was saved
        alert($("tr#"+id).data("polygon"));
    });

    $("table").tablesorter({
        sortLocaleCompare: true,
        widgets: ['zebra']
    }).tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        size: 15
    });
});
```

the polygon:

```
"polygon":[{"x":48.235752,"y":11.685345},{"x":48.21908,"y":11.686883}...]
```

the function that bind the click event to the table line:

```
$('.tableLine').live('click', function (event){
    var polygon = $(this).data("polygon");

    if(polygon){
        addPolygon(polygon);
    }
});
```

Comment: I finally found out that the table sorter caused that problem, when I moved it out from the getJSON() it will work. However the column can not be sorted any more, because the table data was not there during the "initialization" of the table sorter since it has been moved out of the getJSON() function.

Comment: Yes, I also was sure that something rebuild table.

Comment: I tried to save data to an independent DOM, still not work. Although the table would be rebuild, but how about the independent DOM?

Comment: please, provide example, something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/GECVn/

Comment: sorry, I don't want to mess around, but... it worked at this moment without any change(maybe I have restart the server), cache problem? It looks like a very stupid question which I should delete. thank you again for your patient, I am realy sorry for this kind of question

Comment: @uuser1146450 It's ok, don't worry, everything is fine )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, provide your `jsFiddle` example, as I can see your code works in my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c5s5t/1/

Comment: I really should test it myself in the jsfiddle first, it works! so something else causes that problem! thank you anyway.